# Why WebStorm and TypeScript are not prompting me for getter type when using storeToRefs with pinia

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, webstorm, vite, pinia

I have a repository which implementation is via pinia with getter:

```
export const useLanguage = defineStore<string, { current: string }>({
  id: 'language',
  state: () => ({
    current: 'en',
  }),
  getters: {
    currentLanguage: (state): ILanguage =>
      supportedLanguages.get(state.current) as ILanguage,
  },
  persist: true,
})
```

This is how I want to get the reactive getter and use it:

```
const { currentLanguage } = storeToRefs(useLanguage())
```

However, TypeScript and / or WebStorm swears that such a property does not exist:

> Volar: Property 'currentLanguage' does not exist on type 'StoreToRefs  >'.

Perhaps the whole thing is in the Vite config.

I'm already confused, tell me which way to dig.

However, if you run it, the code works. But I still want to get intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to try using `toRefs` instead of `storeToRefs`. This should give you the correct type information for your store.

```js
import { useLanguage } from './your-store';

const store = useLanguage();
const { currentLanguage } = toRefs(store);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, he still does not understand the type

Comment: @рагнаросповелительогня  It would be helpful if you could share the exact error message and any relevant code snippets.

Comment: `Property 'currentLanguage' does not exist on type 'ToRefs<Store<string, { current: string; }, {}, {}>>'.`
This is the error I get when building the code shown above

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it consisted in the fact that I explicitly typed the getters for defineStore leaving it empty. As soon as I removed the typing everything was ok

As example

```
export const useLanguage = defineStore({
  id: 'language',
  state: () => ({
    current: 'en',
  }),
  getters: {
    currentLanguage: (state): ILanguage =>
      supportedLanguages.get(state.current) as ILanguage,
  },
  persist: true,
})
```